# Using convexity to prove integral is nonnegative

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, convex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a convex function and consider the following integral:
$$I = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} f(g(h(t)-c, t)) - f(g(h(t),t)) -f'\big(g(h(t) - c, t) - g(h(t), t)\big) dt$$
where I've abused notation to write
$$f' =  \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial g}(u(h(t), t)).$$
and $c > 0$ is a constant. I would like to show that $I \geq 0$ and this somehow follows from $f$ being convex but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I know you said you’re abusing notation, but $f$ is a function of one variable, writing partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ is terrible. Also, you again have typos: be consistent with the $g$ vs $u$. I would really urge you to reproduce the text verbatim, and atleast mention the source (this helps us readers understand the context, and atleast we can double check if you’re making typos or genuine mistake)… otherwise, please double check your question for typos because it really does affect readability.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh yes sorry, thanks for catching the typo. Is there a better notation that you suggest for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$?

Comment: $f’$ works just fine (and specify the point of evaluation, as you’ve done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I\subset\Bbb{R}$ is an open interval and $f:I\to\Bbb{R}$ is convex and differentiable, then for all $a,b\in I$, we have the inequality
\begin{align}
0\leq f(a)-f(b)-f’(b)[a-b].\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Geometrically, $a\mapsto f(b) +f’(b)[a-b]$ is the equation of the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at the point $b$. The inequality is saying that $f(a)$ is always greater or equal to this value, i.e the graph of $f$ always lies above the tangent line at any point.

Apply this with $a=g(h(t)-c,t)$ and $b=g(h(t),t)$.

---

Why is the inequality $(*)$ above true? Well, for a differentiable convex function, I hope you’re happy with the fact that $f’$ is an increasing function (one can actually refine these statements much more using Dini derivatives, but let’s not get too derailed). So, for any $\alpha,\beta\in I$ with $\alpha<\beta$, we have
\begin{align}
f’(\alpha)\leq \frac{f(\beta)-f(\alpha)}{\beta-\alpha}\leq f’(\beta).\tag{$**$}
\end{align}
Why? Because by the mean-value theorem, there exists some $\theta\in (\alpha,\beta)$ such that the middle term equals $f’(\theta)$. So, by the increasing nature of $f’$ we have these two inequalities.

Now, let $a,b\in I$ be arbitrary.

- If $a<b$, then take $\alpha=a,\beta=b$ and rearrange the second inequality of $(**)$ to get $(*)$.
- If $b<a$, then take $\alpha= b,\beta=a$ and rearrange the first inequality of $(**)$ to get $(*)$.
- If $a=b$, then $(*)$ is obvious.

Comment: Also, while I did answered your question, you should note that your question is in fact a really simple one, and a lot of the complexity disappears once you distill things to their essentials by fixing $t$ and defining $a=g(h(t)-c,t)$ and $b=g(h(t),t)$, so you’re just left with investigating the sign of $f(a)-f(b)=f’(b)[a-b]$… which then really is a simple matter of looking at one of the many ways of looking at convex functions. At this stage you should immediately ask yourself “is there anything I know about convex functions and first derivatives?”

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes you are right, after reading your answer it seems a lot simpler than I had originally thought.